# Mocking and unit testing graphql-dotnet

Tags: c#, unit-testing, graphql, moq, graphql-dotnet

I'm using [graphql-dotnet](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet) library to query some GraphQL APIs from my C# code. Is there a way to easily mock the `GraphQLHttpClient` in unit tests?

Comment: what did you try yourself?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain multiple approaches by mocking the GraphQLHttpClient directly or by passing a mock version of the HttpClient. I ended up with a solution which I've described in the answer bellow (which I thing might be helpful for other users).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to mock the `GraphQLHttpClient` directly but you can provide your own `HttpClient` in one of the `GraphQLHttpClient` constructors and mock the `HttpMessageHandler`. Take a look a the code below:

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(_responseContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = new HttpResponseMessage
{
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
    Content = content
};

var httpMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
httpMessageHandler.Protected()
                  .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
                  .ReturnsAsync(response);

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpMessageHandler.Object);

GraphQLHttpClient graphQlClient = new GraphQLHttpClient(GetOptions(), new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer(), client);
```

The above code works fine and allows me to provide any testing JSON output of the real GQL API I want in the `_responseContent` variable.
The first line and two arguments - `Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"` - are quite important. Without providing the content type, the GraphQLHttpClient will throw an exception because of [this line](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client/blob/d422bfdd0f5e3a1fba2af86c1aa9aaa41e28e495/src/GraphQL.Client/GraphQLHttpClientOptions.cs#L70). It took me a while to find it.

I'm using `Moq` library for mocking objects.

Comment: So, it seems like it comes down to mocking good old HttpMessageHandler, as is the case with all solutions using hardcoded depndency on `HttpClient`

Answer (score 0):

The `GraphQLHttpClient` implements the `IGraphQLWebSocketClient` which extends the `IGraphQLClient`. The `IGraphQLClient` describes the following methods:

```
Task<GraphQLResponse<TResponse>> SendQueryAsync<TResponse>(GraphQLRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
        
Task<GraphQLResponse<TResponse>> SendMutationAsync<TResponse>(GraphQLRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

Then in your test code you can provide a moq for the `IGraphQLClient`. You only have to be aware that you are using Dependency Injection in combination with the provided interface.

It could be look like this here:

```
public class UnitTest1
{
   [Fact]
   public void Test1()
   {
      var mockedService = new Mock<IGraphQLClient>();
      mockedService
         Setup(ms => ms.SendQueryAsync<string>(It.IsAny<GraphQLRequest>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
         .ReturnsAsync(new GraphQLResponse<string>());

         var service = new AnythingWithGraphQLDependency(mockedService.Object);

   }
}

public class AnythingWithGraphQLDependency
{
   private readonly IGraphQLClient _client;

   public AnythingWithGraphQLDependency(IGraphQLClient client)
   {
      _client = client;
   }

   public async Task<string> Test(string query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
      var response = await _client.SendQueryAsync<string>(new GraphQLRequest(query), cancellationToken);

      //Code to be tested goes here
   }
}
```